# K-theory product trivial on $K^1$ due to stability?

Tags: algebraic-topology, vector-bundles, topological-k-theory, k-theory

Let $K^0$ be the topological complex vector bundle $K$-theory functor. On the one hand, we have that the product on $K^0(\Sigma X)$ vanishes by a Mayer-Vietoris argument. On the other hand, we define $K^1(X) = K^{-1}(X)=K^0(\Sigma X)$, hence is it correct to conclude the graded product for the topological $K$-theory ring vanishes in all odd degrees?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not. Recall that by the Chern character isomorphism, rational K-theory is periodic rational cohomology, so the cup product on odd rational K-theory doesn't vanish in any situation where the cup product on odd rational cohomology doesn't vanish; the simplest example is $S^1 \times S^1$.

The stability argument is irrelevant because the cup product is not a stable operation. The cup product on $K^0(\Sigma X)$ is an operation $K^0(\Sigma X) \times K^0(\Sigma X) \to K^0(\Sigma X)$ but the cup product on $K^1(X)$ is an operation $K^1(X) \times K^1(X) \to K^2(X) \cong K^0(X)$; these operations have nothing to do with each other. Note that your argument applies equally well, and is equally irrelevant, to ordinary cohomology.

Comment: Thank you, Qiaochu. Yes, my mistake was thinking the cup product on $K^{-1}$ was just the cup of $K^0$, which would imply cup is stable, so I should have known better.

But that leaves me now wondering how the cup product on $K^{-1}$ actually is defined. I guess it should look like $K^{-1}(X)\otimes K^{-1}(X)\to K^0(\Sigma X)\otimes K^0(\Sigma X)\to K^0(\Sigma X\wedge \Sigma X)\to K^0(S^2\wedge X\wedge X)\cong K^0(X\wedge X)\overset{\Delta^*}{\to} K^0(X).$

Comment: Would the following be a correct summary of the situation?

The tensor product of two vector bundles on a suspension is stably trivial on the suspension, but the external product need not be trivial on the double suspension, and the cup product is the pullback by $\Delta$ of the latter.

Comment: Maybe? I admit I don't actually know how the cup product on $K^1$ is defined.